Pandas memory_usage inconsistent for in-line numpy
Could someone help explain why there's a difference of results here?
In particular, the memory usage outputted after serialization/deserialization is dramatically different.
The only clue I have is that df["data"][0].flags outputs 'OWNDATA` differently from the latter.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "data": [np.random.randint(size=1024, low=0, high=100, dtype=np.int8) for _ in range(1_000_000)]
})

print(df["data"].size, df["data"].dtype, df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum())
# 1000000 object 1144000132
df2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(df))
print(df2["data"].size, df2["data"].dtype, df2.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum())
# 1000000 object 120000132

print(np.array_equal(df["data"][0], df2["data"][0])) 


I'm not quite ready to be definitive about it, but df2 is too small to hold the data and the flag says it doesn't own the data. My guess is that pickle somehow used a view or reference to an array while building the dataframe. Its referencing an anonymous array somewhere and isn't counting that in memory usage.

My comments were getting long, so I put them here as an answer.
The bottom line is: this is a numpy problem, not a pandas problem. From the point of view of pandas, what you have here is an array of 1000000 rows and 1 single column, containing 1000000 "objects", that is opaque, external pointers, that pandas know nothing about, only it is able to store them, and give them back to you if you ask for them.
This is why, if you had just asked for df.memory_usage(), you would have got the exact same answer before and after.
Because, from pandas perspective, that is all that matters. That is what is stored in a pandas dataframe, using 120000132 bytes (132 for indexes, and 1000000 × 120, that 120 bytes for each of the "pointers" to an external unknown data. 120 is the size of the "pointer")
But you added deep=True. And the docs says that if you do so, pandas will ask for system level memory usage of objects.
Which it does
import sys
arr1=df.data[0]
arr2=df2.data[0]
print(sys.getsizeof(arr1)  # 1136
print(sys.getsizeof(arr2) # 112

So, what you got (with 8 bytes of overhead for both - the pointer, hence the quotes hitheto = 120 what the size of the pointer, plus the size of dataless numpy array)
Note that df.data[0] and df2.data[0] are just numpy array, with nothing to do with pandas. Hence my usage of intermediary variables, to get rid of pandas. Once I have them in arr1 and arr2, I don't use any pandas code to do the rest.
So, question is why, arr1 and arr2, that are apparently the same arrays ((arr1==arr2).all() is True), have different sizes, from sys.getsizeof.
And you gave the answer: arr1.flags contains OWNDATA, arr2.flags doesn't.
arr1 is a plain array (you created yourself, with np.random.randint).
While, as tdelaney said in comment, arr2 is made, by pickle, from a byte-string.
Which you can see
arr1.base # None
arr2.base # b'stuf'

Which is not surprising at all. You would expect pickle to read bytes from a file, and then build numpy array from those bytes
Just a mock up thing of what happens
arr1=np.arange(4, dtype=np.uint8)
arr2=np.frombuffer(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03', dtype=np.uint8)
arr1, arr2 # both array([0,1,2,3])
arr1.base, arr2.base # None and b'\x00\x01\x02\x03'
arr1.flags.owndata, arr2.flags.owndata # True, False
# Hence
sys.getsizeof(arr1), sys.getsizeof(arr2) # 116, 112 : 4 bytes of data counted in arr1, but not arr2 (since they belong to the byte string that still exist as a python object in memory)
# Hence, to be complete — but again, pandas has nothing to do with that
# Just, its "deep" computation of memory usage reflect the size of the
# objects it stores. And arr1 and arr2 doesn't have the same sizes
# from python point of view.
df1=pd.DataFrame({"data":[arr1]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"data":[arr2]})
df1.memory_usage(deep=True).sum(), df2.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
# 256, 252 : still the 4 bytes of data, counted in the "deep" size of 
# opaque object that points to arr1 (because getsizeof(arr1) counts it)
# and not in the one of arr2

So, tl;dr
np.frombuffer(bytestring)

doesn't own its data. The bytestring is another python object.
While
np.random.randint(...)

does (there is no other python objects that the numpy array involved)
Which makes the python system size of those two numpy array differents. Which reflects on what you get with df.memory_usage with option deep=True

It was obvious that the object dtype of the column was the issue.  At  first I wondered if pickle didn't go deep enough, but you've shown that it's memory_usage that doesn't go deep enough.  getsizeof usually works better on arrays than on lists, but still has its limits when dealing with views.
